# How to fix the scaling problem in Continuum?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, display, continuum

My Lumia 950 XL comes with Windows 10 Mobile. When I connect it to Microsoft Display Dock and the TV, part of the screen is outside of the TV. I know this is a scaling problem, and can be resolved by going into display adapter's property to fix it like in regular Windows 10. But since the OS is Windows 10 Mobile, there is no display adapter property I can change.

I can't find any settings on the TV either. Is this a known problem?

Firmware: 01078.00017.15454.29005
OS: 10.0.10586.63 (with insider fast lane)

Comment: What is the TV? What connection are you using on the TV (DVI/HDMI/etc.)? I've had issues in the past where my TV would overstretch signals from my various laptops and not show the edges of the screen.

Comment: The TV is Toshiba 55L310U connected with HDMI.

Answer (score 2):

You need to download the "Wireless Display Adapter" application from the store. Once connected to your Wireless Display Adapter you can launch the app and change the scaling...